# Anything here that can be blocking my site from being indexed by Google / Bing?

Tags: seo, htaccess

I'm unable to get my site indexed by Google or Bing. Robots and sitemap have been submitted but no love... I think the issue may be in the .htaccess file.

Is there anything in here that may be causing problems? Thanks.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

Redirect 301 "/aboutus" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/about-us/"
Redirect 301 "/code-of-conduct" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/code-of-conduct/"
Redirect 301 "/terms-of-use" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/terms-and-conditions/"
Redirect 301 "/FAQ" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/faq-how-to/"
Redirect 301 "/privacy" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/privacy-policy/"
Redirect 301 "/contact" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/contact-us/"
Redirect 301 "/resources" "https://quiz.redacted.com/new/resources/"
Redirect 301 "/Resources" "https://quiz.edacted.com/new/resources/"

RedirectMatch 403 ^/photo/viewlist/.*$
RewriteRule ^index$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/e500\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/captcha\.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.htm|\.feed|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Comment: Your .htaccess looks bad, but nothing from your .htaccess is blocking search engine, I think you just need to wait for more time.

Comment: OK will do... BTW: what would make it look better?